How can we interpret long-range entanglement in the context of the Hubbard model?
How can we interpret long-range entanglement in the context of the Hubbard model, particularly with respect to its implications for quantum phases like superconductivity and other strongly correlated states?
I’m exploring the role of long-range entanglement in the Hubbard model, especially as it relates to superconducting phases and other correlated phenomena. How does long-range entanglement manifest in these systems, and what insights can be gained from studying entanglement entropy, correlation functions, or other measures in this context? Additionally, how does this entanglement connect to phenomena such as quantum phase transitions or topological order within the framework of the Hubbard model?
